# Распаковка списка из словарей на Python

Tags: python

У меня есть список из 3-х словарей. Далее я распаковываю этот список в 3 переменных. Каждая содержит один словарь. Далее я создаю функцию, которая будет принимать 2 аргумента, и в вызове функции нужно распаковывать словарь. Потом вызываю фунцкцию 3 раза, но получаю ошибку.

```py
dict_list = [{'one': 1, 'one_one': 11}, {'two': 2, 'two_two': 22}, {'three': 3, 'three_three': 33}]
one, two, three = dict_list

def myFunc(name, digit):
    print(f"name {name}, digit: {digit}")


myFunc(**one)    # Вывод: name is 1 and digit is 11
myFunc(**two)    # Вывод: name is 2 and digit is 22
myFunc(**three)  # Вывод: name is 3 and digit is 33
```

А этот пример из ChatGPT и он работает, но я не понимаю почему:

```py
dict_list = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 35}]

# Распаковываем словари в переменные
var1, var2, var3 = dict_list

# Создаем функцию, которая принимает два аргумента и распаковывает словарь
def print_person_info(name, age):
    print(f"Имя: {name}, Возраст: {age}")

# Вызываем функцию 3 раза, каждый раз передавая разные переменные
print_person_info(**var1)
print_person_info(**var2)
print_person_info(**var3)
```

Ведь и там, и там одно и тоже просто текст другой, я не понимаю где у меня ошибка.

Ошибка, которую получаю в консоли:

```
TypeError: myFunc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'one'
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь запихнуть в функцию `myFunc` параметры с именами `one` и `one_one` из словаря, но очевидно же, что в функции таких параметров нет и там есть только `name` и `digit`

Comment: @andreymal я понял. я ответил там сам себе, можете посмотреть и сказать правильно ли я понял.

Answer (score 0):

Все, я понял. Нужно было указывать те же самые ключи в качестве параметров функции что и в словарях. Видимо для различных вариантов не работает.